# Creating a Mobile Application with chat functionality native Android using FCM/GCM

Tags: android, performance, api, google-cloud-messaging, chat

I have tried creating a mobile application with User Management, Social Networking, Work sharing , Chat capability between the users in a single and group manner.

Initially, I had used MBaas platforms such as quickblox and Parse. Quickblox seemed to be the best fit for my application requirements since the way creating Custom Classes ( easy to create Model classes to map my requirement which supports Entity relationships ) but felt the platform to be bit immature and bugs popped up every now and then during API calls( though used Quickblox free edition due to very stringent budget constraint usually for a Startup). 
Parse , on the other hand in my limited research found to have limitations for while scaling to larger application with Pricing as well as performance.
Now, on deciding to use FCM ( recently Google moving on from GCM to FCM )
as the chatting functionality.So the other core functionalities such as user and their group related features to a separate web application which communicates to the Google Server.My doubts revolves around the points below

- It seems that FCM supports only text messages ( don't know whether
  its limited too?) and no media or file attachment support?
- found the Google Firebase Console has a Database support. Is it only
  for the chat messages sync or it can be customised to add further
  functionalities ( my other functionalities in this App )
- Or else if using separate web application to manage functionalities
  apart from chat and FCM for chat would be good enough architecture?
- If using separate application , will the file or media attachments
  for the chat be an issue?or any other strategy can be used here for
  such  scenarios?

Appreciate your valuable thoughts . This would really help us incorporate valuable tips upfront in development process . 
Thanks in advance.